# Prove that F^{*} is a field if and only if X is one-element set.

Tags: field-theory

(F,&,#) is a field, X is a set. Consider ($F^x$, &*, #*), where the operations are the usual operations on function. Prove that $F^{x}$ is a field if and only if X is one-element set.

I don't really know what $F^x$, &*, #* is.

Comment: "I don't really know what ... is" are we supposed to help you figure it out?

Comment: My guess is that it should be $F^X$, which is the set of functions from $X$ to $F$. In this context, for $f$ and $g$ in $F^X$, $f\&^* g$ takes $y\in F$ to $f(y)\& g(y)$ and $f\#^* g$ takes $y$ to $f(y)\# g(y)$.

Comment: @KennyLau I thought that Is just a mathematical standard knowledge that I am lacking. There were not other informations given during the exam about this task and about meaning of $F^x$

Answer (score 1):

Using more standard notation and fixing the typo $x\to X$, you want to prove that, given $F$ a field, the set $F^X$ of functions $X\to F$, with operations
$$
\alpha+\beta\colon x\mapsto \alpha(x)+\beta(x)
\qquad
\alpha\beta\colon x\mapsto \alpha(x)\beta(x)
$$
(which is a ring, with easy checks) is a field if and only if $X$ is a one element set.

If $X$ is empty, then $F^X$ is a one element set, so not a field.

If $X$ has two distinct elements $x_1$ and $x_2$, define
$$
\alpha(x)=\begin{cases}
1 & x=x_1\\
0 & x\ne x_1
\end{cases}
\qquad
\beta(x)=\begin{cases}
1 & x=x_2\\
0 & x\ne x_2
\end{cases}
$$
What can you say about the product $\alpha\beta$? Are the elements $\alpha$ and $\beta$ the zero element?